# Error when running java project

Tags: java

I've used this compiler till now and I've never had any problems with it, but now, when I run the following code (in Eclipse LUNA, latest version):

```
import java.sql.*;

public class TestJDBC {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database";
        String user = "user";
        String password = "root";
        try {
            Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Eroare incarcare driver!\n" + e);
        }
        try {
            Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, user, password);
            Statement s= c.createStatement();
            ResultSet r = s.executeQuery(" SELECT cod, nume FROM localitati"
                                         + " ORDER BY nume");

            while (r.next()) {
                System.out.println(r.getString ("cod") + "," + r.getString ("nume") );
            }
            s.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
  at TestJDBC.main(TestJDBC.java:8)
   Eroare incarcare driver!
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
  java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
  at TestJDBC.main(TestJDBC.java:15)
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Your classpath lacks the jar that contains the `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver` class.

Answer (score 0):

Your build is missing a JAR library in the build path.
You can get it here:

1. Download the [Latest MySQL Java Connector / Drive](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)r
2. Unzip the zip file (in my case it was mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.zip)
3. copy the .jar file (mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar) and paste it in your Lib folder:

Than do not forget to add the jar library to your build path.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver` Exception came because of you don't have that class in your application.

To resolve issue you have to check is that class present in your `lib` file given or download and configure `mysql-2_0_12.jar` jar file it will support `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver` driver.

Answer (score 0):

Download mysql driver jar [click here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/Downloadmysql2012jar.htm)

Add the jar in build path